# gatsby-background-image with svg not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import styled from 'styled-components'
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image'
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "./layout.css"

const BizTech = ({ className }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        desktop: file(relativePath: { eq: "foobar.svg" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 1920) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => {
      // Set ImageData.
      const imageData = data.desktop.childImageSharp.fluid

      const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      speed: 500,
      cssEase: "linear"
    };
      return (
        <BackgroundImage Tag="section" className={className} fluid={imageData} backgroundColor={`transparent`} style={{ }}>
          <div style={{ }}>
            <h3>FOOBAR</h3>
          </div>
        </BackgroundImage>
      )
    }}
  />
)

const StyledBT = styled(BizTech)`
  width: 100%;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: cover;
`
export default StyledBT
```

When the referenced image file is a JPG, it's found and displayed.  If it's an SVG as above, it is not.

Comment: `gatsby-plugin-sharp` / `gatsby-image` doesn't handle SVGs or GIFs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ksav pointed out in the comments, the use of SVG source files is not currently supported by the sharp node pipeline integration.

Comment: I wonder if that is a TBD thing or an actual technical limitation somewhere. I really want to use an SVG to obtain the sharpness at high screen size.

Comment: @mtyson Well the whole point of the integration is to allow you to generate multiple copies of raster images for srcSet usage. Since SVGs are typically vector data, you don't need to do any resizing or make multiple copies, just embed them directly.

Comment: ok, so just do it the old fashioned way.  It might make sense to support SVG so it can be handled consistently by client code, even if it just passes the vector un-modified.

Comment: @mtyson Yeah, I had similar gripes when I discovered this for the first time, particularly for cases where content is coming from a CMS where editors might inadvertently upload an SVG image where a raster is expected. I've since moved away from having Gatsby handle image transformations or srcSets in a majority of cases.

Comment: What is the alternative solution to using SVG as a background image in Gatsby? Do I need to resort to importing it as a regular file?
Likes so...
import blobshape from '../../../../../images/svg/blob-shape-1.svg';

Comment: @Aquasar If you really need it to be a CSS background, you can use that approach or fetch the `src` from the image. You just can't do sharp transformations on the image (i.e. using `fluid` or `fixed`).

Answer (score 1):

I know there's an accepted answer, but for anyone still looking for a possible solution, hopefully this helps:

I ended up putting the SVG in the static folder and then referenced that as an inline style to the div that I wanted to have the SVG background image. Like so:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/static/bg.svg)` }}>
```